# Using Google Custom Search Engine in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-custom-search

I have a problem when using GCSE(Google Custom Search Engine) in ReactJS. My code shows like below:

```
class Input extends React.Component {

  conponentDidMount() {
    var myCallback = function() {
       if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
          google.search.cse.element.render(
          {
            div: "root",
            tag: 'search'
         });
       } else {
           google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
              google.search.cse.element.render(
              {
                div: "root",
                tag: 'search'
              });
           }, true);
   }
};

window.__gcse = {
  parsetags: 'explicit',
  callback: myCallback
};

  (function() {
    var cx = '008391824253360889328:j5posmpyok0';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
    console.log(window.__gcse);
}

  render() {
    return(
      <div className = "content">
        <div className="gcse-searchbox" data-resultsUrl="http://www.google.com" data-newWindow="true" data-queryParameterName="search" >
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Input/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

It didn't show the search bar. And I don't know how to change such code in React. I have read the document from https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5. But I still cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting in console ?
By the way... you have a typo at `conponentDidMount` it should be `componentDidMount`

Comment: Wow, this typo makes the problem. It can work successfully. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.